# createUserWithEmailAndPassword with AngularFireAuth and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am beginner using Angularfire 2 and Firebase.

Using the official documentation of this two tools, I saw that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` was called in two different ways by AngularFireAuth :

```
constructor( public fire : AngularFireAuth ) {
    this.fire.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.uname.value,this.password.value)
}
```

or by firebase :

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

I need to know is there any difference or it is the same .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's the same, yes.

The upper example is simply the implementation with Angularfire, the other one is the implementation from the plain JS SDK. If you're using Angularfire anyways you should use the upper for consistency.

Comment: So, the two examples works the same.
Thank you @sandrooco

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being clear, I updated the answer a bit. @AmirChoubani